# Is there an implementation of this query-syntax in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

In some SQL dialects, you can state (something as):

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE (val1,val2) IN 
  (SELECT val1,val2 FROM SomeOtherTable)
```

But I don't know how to do that in the TSQL (sql server 2k) I am using.

I am aware  of (and using for now) workarounds like using joins or concatenated values, 
but is there some syntax in TSQL I am overlooking to do just that?

UPDATE : This is valid SQL-99 syntax, that's why I consider a join a workaround, even if it would be more performant.  My question is maybe put better as :

**Is there an implementation of this syntax in TSQL?**

UPDATE2 : I just tested this syntax om Mysql and it works fine there.

Comment: I wouldn't call using joins a _workaround_.  I'm not a SQL expert, but pretty sure a JOIN is going to be much faster than using IN.

Comment: @Rake: Depends on the IN clause. In this case, splitting these up into subselects will (and using per row filtering), in fact, be slower than a join.

Comment: @Rake: SQL Server can optimize. There is a special SEMI JOIN algorithm designed specially for such cases. It's faster than a JOIN with subsequent DISTINCT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    SomeTable st
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    SomeOtherTable sot
        WHERE   sot.val1 = st.val1
                AND sot.val2 = st.val2
        )
```

This is actually what an `IN` construct is optimized to with any `SEMI JOIN` method.

As for your question,

> Is there an implementation of this syntax in `T-SQL`?

the answer is **no**

As [**documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682(SQL.90).aspx) says:

> … `subquery` that has a result set of **one** column. This column must have the same data type as `test_expression`.

Comment: @Peter: how did you make such a short comment?

Comment: @Peter: … and I thought I know something of computers …

Answer (score 4):

There is not a sql server implementation of that syntax.  You'll have to do something like this:

```
SELECT st.*
FROM SomeTable st
  INNER JOIN  
  (
    SELECT val1, val2 
    FROM SomeOtherTable 
    GROUP BY val1, val2
  ) sot ON sot.val1= st.val1 AND sot.val2 = st.val2
```

Comment: In no single version? Not even 2008?

Answer (score 1):

Joining would be the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

IN only works on single column arrays.  Since you've explicitly stated that you want to do an IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable 
WHERE val1 IN (SELECT val1 FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE val2 = SomeTable.val2) 
AND val2 IN (SELECT val2 FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE val1 = SomeTable.val1)
```

Check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682(SQL.90).aspx) on it.  Since there's a where clause which depended on each row (e.g.-WHERE SomeOtherTable.ID = SomeTable.MyOtherID), it will hose performance, and a join is absolutely the way to go.

Comment: Not the same, because the matching val1 and val2 might come from different rows in SomeOtherTable

Comment: That would not necessarily work, would it? It could give you a match if there is a row in SomeOtherTable that has val1 matching but not val2 (and vice versa) as long as there was another row that was able to match the other value.

Comment: in only works on single column arrays in all sql-server versions?

Comment: @Peter: According to W3C this is standard: http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_in.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
Select SomeTable.*
FROM SomeTable, SomeOtherTable
WHERE SomeTable.Val1 = SomeOtherTable.Val1
    And SomeTable.Val2 = SoemeOtherTable.Val2
```

You should not consider this a "workaround." This is the most basic and standard way of accomplishing what you want to accomplish.

Edit: It may not be your standard "JOIN" syntax, but it's a habit.

Comment: This could cause duplicate results if SomeOtherTable has more than one record with val1 and val2 columns that match a record from SomeTable.

Comment: Good point Joel. Didn't think about the duplicate results being an unnecessary side effect.

Comment: Joel: Old habits are hard to break (concerning the syntax). That was the way I was originally taught and it stuck with me for this long because when I'm constructing a query in my head that's how it sounds instead of thinking about the word JOIN.

Comment: @theTXI  I do consider join a workaround, for my example is valid SQL99 syntax

Comment: @TXI: It was a habit for me for a long time, too. I started doing it on here as "good practice," and it's broken my habit, methinks.

Comment: Eric: I try to do the same most times, but every once in a while I'll let something like this slip in when I start thinking too fast.

Comment: @TheTXI: my name is Quassnoi and I am a joinless syntax user. But I made significant progress since I joined Stack Overflow, and for now I almost gave up using (+) for OUTER JOINs in Oracle even in projects nobody but me sees.